# JMeter Plugin or Java Issue?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We are currently working on a test script in which my colleague encounters an error when she tries to open my .jmx file. I've pasted the jmeter log file below. So far, we have the same Java versions, JMeter versions and virtually the same installed plugins in JMeter. We have tried opening the .jmx file on other users' JMeter tool and no issue was encountered. Is there a solution to this?

```
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\user.properties 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\system.properties 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2016 The Apache Software Foundation 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 3.1 r1770033 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_121 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Max memory     =523763712 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Available Processors =4 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\apache-jmeter-3.1 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2017/02/09 09:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2017/02/09 09:04:01 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2017/02/09 09:04:01 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2017/02/09 09:04:03 INFO  - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-graphs-basic=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-graphs-additional=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-autostop=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-sense=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-cmd=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-graphs-composite=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-csl=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-functions=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-casutg=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-dbmon=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-graphs-dist=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-dummy=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-ftp=3.1, jpgc-filterresults=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-ffw=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-ggl=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-http=3.1, jpgc-httpraw=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-sts=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-fifo=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-jdbc=3.1, jpgc-jms=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-jms=3.1, jpgc-jmxmon=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-monitors=3.1, jmeter-core=3.1, jpgc-json=2.5, jmeter-junit=3.1, jmeter-java=3.1, jpgc-graphs-vs=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-ldap=3.1, jpgc-lockfile=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-mail=3.1, jpgc-mergeresults=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-mongodb=3.1, jpgc-oauth=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-native=3.1, jpgc-pde=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-prmctl=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-perfmon=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-plugins-manager=0.11, jpgc-redis=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-synthesis=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-tcp=3.1, jpgc-plancheck=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-tst=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-udp=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-csvars=0.0.0-STOCK, jmeter-components=3.1, jpgc-wsc=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-xml=0.0.0-STOCK, jpgc-standard=2.0] 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\keytool' 
2017/02/09 09:04:05 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.MonitorHealthVisualizer 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2017/02/09 09:04:06 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2017/02/09 09:04:26 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin' 
2017/02/09 09:04:26 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\M3 BE TA\M3 BE Regression Test Suite\Test Plans\CARAP\PO_GR-IVM.jmx 
2017/02/09 09:04:26 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\M3 BE TA\M3 BE Regression Test Suite\Test Plans\CARAP' 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.1 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\M3 BE TA\M3 BE Regression Test Suite\Test Plans\CARAP\PO_GR-IVM.jmx 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET] 
2017/02/09 09:04:27 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'C:\M3 BE TA\M3 BE Regression Test Suite\Test Plans\CARAP\PO_GR-IVM.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[4]/BeanShellSampler/stringProp
line number         : 112
version             : 3.1 r1770033
-------------------------------
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:537)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:505)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:89)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[4]/BeanShellSampler/stringProp
line number         : 112
version             : 3.1 r1770033
-------------------------------
at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.createConversionException(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:103)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:97)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1230)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1214)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1085)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:522)
... 22 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       : 
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.StringPropertyConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[4]/BeanShellSampler/stringProp
line number         : 112
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:73)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter.unmarshal(ScriptWrapperConverter.java:95)
... 32 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: 
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:124)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:148)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:135)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.getValue(AbstractPullReader.java:180)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.ReaderWrapper.getValue(ReaderWrapper.java:48)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.ConversionHelp.getPropertyValue(ConversionHelp.java:245)
at org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.StringPropertyConverter.unmarshal(StringPropertyConverter.java:62)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
... 60 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected character in markup < (position: START_TAG seen ...oice match on line level with internal and external line charge\n<<... @112:3) 
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1261)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:109)
... 67 more
```

Comment: check the line in `.jmx` file by opening it in some editor like `notepad++`. make the element used that line is present in the JMeter (either builtin or Plugin). Please confirm whether you and your colleague's machines are having `same Java, JMeter & JMeter Plugins` versions. From log, I found that `3.1 r1770033` is being used. so compare with other JMeter version.

Comment: Can you please post what's at line 112 of the `C:\M3 BE TA\M3 BE Regression Test Suite\Test Plans\CARAP\PO_GR-IVM.jmx` script?
It could be wrong encoding for example, but hard to say without seeing it

Comment: @ Naveen: I've opened the the .jmx file in Notepad++ but the specific line this points to (112) is a csv file. We both have the same plugins installed, same Java version and same JMeter version.

Comment: @ Kiril S.: As I mentioned in my comment above, it points to a csv file. Posting line: 

//props.put(&quot;aps450mi_csv&quot;, &quot;/M3 BE Regression Test Suite/Test Plans/CARAP/IVM_Common Data for Invoice Match Scenario/APS450MI-AddHead.csv&quot;);

Is there a better way to declare csv files? Please note it is not part of our standard to use the 'CSV Data Set Config' element to declare csvs.

Answer (score 0):

confirming that this issue has been resolved. The .jmx file was corrupted and my colleague just deleted it and performed an SVN update. The script now works fine. Thanks for the help guys!